# Is there an algorithm who finds permutations without repitition from a two dimensional list?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration, time-complexity

My input consists of a two dimensional list of integer values.
The the two dimensional list could hold three lists like the example below:

```
L1   L2    L3
--------------
1    11    111
2    22    222
3    33
4
```

The goal is to combine every element with every other element in the right order.
The result must be a two dimensional list, too.
Every list in the two dimensional list has a size of n, where n is the number of the input lists.
The following result would be generated:

```
L1:  1, 11, 111
L2:  1, 11, 222
L3:  1, 22, 111
L4:  1, 22, 222
L5:  1, 33, 111
L6:  1, 33, 222

L7:  2, 11, 111
L8:  2, 11, 222
L9:  2, 22, 111
.
.
.
L24: 4, 33, 222
```

It is necessary that everything has the right order like the example illustrates.

Comment: Are you looking for a generic approach or for a final implementation?

Comment: You need the *Cartesian product* of `L1, L2, L3`. Can be done recursively.

Comment: @NicoHaase Both are accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved recursively. The algorithm is pretty straightforward, the only tricky part is to avoid duplicated permutations when a list has duplicated numbers. A good way of doing this is to sort each list, so when picking integers from each list, it is very easy to tell if a particular number has been picked or not. The following is the implementation with your provided example as a test case. You can change a list's value to contain duplicated numbers and see that the output does not contain duplicated permutations.

```
public class ListPermutation {
    public static List<List<Integer>> generateUniqueListPermutations(List<List<Integer>> lists) {
        List<List<Integer>> permutations = new ArrayList<>();
        if(lists == null || lists.size() == 0) {
            return permutations;
        }
        //sort each input list
        for(List<Integer> list : lists) {
            Collections.sort(list);
        }
        permutationHelper(lists, permutations, new ArrayList<>(), 0);
        return permutations;
    }
    private static void permutationHelper(List<List<Integer>> lists, List<List<Integer>> permutations, List<Integer> list, int idx) {
        if(idx == lists.size()) {
            permutations.add(new ArrayList<>(list));
            return;
        }
        List<Integer> currList = lists.get(idx);
        for(int i = 0; i < currList.size(); i++) {
            if(i > 0 && currList.get(i) == currList.get(i - 1)) {
                continue;
            }
            list.add(currList.get(i));
            permutationHelper(lists, permutations, list, idx + 1);
            list.remove(list.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); list1.add(1); list1.add(2); list1.add(3); list1.add(4);
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(); list2.add(11); list2.add(22); list2.add(33);
        List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>(); list3.add(111); list3.add(222);
        List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>(); lists.add(list1); lists.add(list2); lists.add(list3);
        generateUniqueListPermutations(lists);
    }
}
```